# Multiple matches for multi condition lookup array with with dates involved

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a list of items which do have a date attached in one list:

[image]

In the 2nd list I have an Item a Date Start and Stop stamp an a Reference ID. 
Goal is to get the reference ID to each Item in list 1, if the time is between Start and Stop time in the list 2.

Now, I got this part right :o)

The trouble I have is when the 2nd list contains more possible reference IDs for the Item & Time combination. Any ideas please?

For the lookup I am using:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(1;(G2>=$C$2:$C$16)*(G2<=$D$2:$D$16)*(H2=$A$2:$A$16);0)+1;5))
```

This is a little bit of work where I am trying to match what happened with what was planned.

The expected output is actually in columns Finding (1,2...). In the red highlighted cell, there is supposed to be ID003 but I am stuck on how to get it there ;/

Comment: for some reason I cannot paste images to the question so sharing a link so u guys see how the file looks like ![my file](https://imgur.com/a/TZN2njO)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Could you attach input and expected output samples?

Answer (score 0):

I've been actually able to resolve this eventually:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$26;SMALL(IF(($F2>=$B$2:$B$26)*($F2<=$C$2:$C$26)*($G2=$A$2:$A$26);ROW($A$2:$A$26)-ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$26;1;1))+1);1))
=INDEX($D$2:$D$26;SMALL(IF(($F2>=$B$2:$B$26)*($F2<=$C$2:$C$26)*($G2=$A$2:$A$26);ROW($A$2:$A$26)-ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$26;1;1))+1);2))
```